# Bulk-add images as nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: media

### Here's what I have:

- An Image node type that includes an image file field and a node reference list that lists nodes of type "gallery"
- A Gallery node type that lists taxonomy terms and stuff
- A View that displays all Images associated with a given Gallery
- Users with role Photographer who will be adding pictures to those galleries for which they have permissions
- Users with role Admin who will be able to edit Image and Gallery nodes and administer Taxonomies.

### Here's what I need:

- A user-friendly bulk upload interface, preferably point-and-click-and-drag, that will allow Photographers to upload, say 100 photos at a time into their own directory
- Bulk creation of Image nodes, one for each image that's uploaded
- Bulk assignment a value to the "Gallery" reference field (both upon bulk node creation and also for already-created nodes)

### Here's my question about it:

- How can I offer user-friendly bulk upload options for Drupal 7?
- ... which would also support bulk node creation?
- ... and which would also bulk populate field values?

Suggestions of (stable!) modules are welcome, as are coding solutions.

Comment: I had an answer all planned out...right up until you threw the word _stable_ in there. Back to the drawing board ;)

Comment: Feel free to interpret "stable" loosely. Like, modules in beta are okay as long as they *work*.

Comment: Seriously. Anybody, please suggest something for bulk upload/node creation. How does Drupal not have this?